# Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-install-_p77_6kw/poster/

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

pip3 install poster

Looking in indexes: http://mirrors.aliyun.com/pypi/simple/

Collecting poster

Downloading 
http://mirrors.aliyun.com/pypi/packages/9f/dc/0683a458d21c3d561ab2f71b4fcdd812bf04e55c54e560b0854cea95610e/poster-0.8.1.tar.gz

```
Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:

Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>

  File "/tmp/pip-install-_p77_6kw/poster/setup.py", line 2, in <module>
    import poster
  File "/tmp/pip-install-_p77_6kw/poster/poster/__init__.py", line 29, in <module>
    import poster.streaminghttp
  File "/tmp/pip-install-_p77_6kw/poster/poster/streaminghttp.py", line 61
    print "send:", repr(value)
                ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

----------------------------------------
```

Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-install-_p77_6kw/poster/

this question may python2 and python3 with here？ help mi

Comment: i do not know what i can do the version issues

Comment: where i can get poster at python3

Comment: is over i kill it

Answer (score 0):

According to [issue #24](https://bitbucket.org/chrisatlee/poster/issues/24/not-working-with-python3) in [the poster repository on bitbucket](https://bitbucket.org/chrisatlee/poster), poster only works on python versions 2.4 to 2.7. You'll need to either use python2 for your project, port the poster code to python3 yourself, or find another solution.

Comment: thinks try again：）

Comment: but  not i can do in ubantu

Answer (score 0):

[github](https://github.com/wangzilong1997/poster-0.8.1) may can help y use 2to3 at poster

Comment: i think so but have the other on question